# Snowpipe skips files

Tags: snowflake-pipe

We have used Snowpipe for ~10 months now and we recently ran into a case where part of the files in a `stage` got uploaded to the corresponding snowflake table and any future files were not detected. Verified that the underlying `stage` and `pipe` were in valid states.

Let's assume that the staging location is s3://<some_bucket>/some/path and there are 5 files file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv, file4.csv, file5.csv

```
select metadata$filename, count(*) from @<DB_NAME>.<SCHEMA>.<STAGE_NAME> group by metadata$filename;
```

The output indicates that all 5 files were detected and the counts align with what's expected. But file4.csv and file5.csv never got ingested.

```
select * from table(information_schema.copy_history(table_name=>'<TABLE_NAME>', start_time=> dateadd(hours, -1000, current_timestamp())));
```

does not show the copy history which makes us suspect if the table/pipe is in non-deterministic state and if there's a way out of this.

Note: the `copy_history` command works for other tables in the database.